# how do I convert a list into a counter object in python

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a list which looks like this:

```
myList = [('string1', 48), ('string2', 48), ('string3', 18)]
```

how can I convert this into a counter? I've already this:

```
newCounter = Counter(myList)
```

but I seem to still be getting a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `newCounter` you'll be able to see it's already a counter object:

```
Counter({('string3', 18): 1, ('string1', 48): 1, ('string2', 48): 1})
```

Also see the type of `newCounter`:

```
print type(newCounter)
<class 'collections.Counter'>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're definitely not getting a list. You're not getting the Counter you want, because the Counter constructor will count an iterable it's provided instead of treating it as a list of key-value pairs, so turn the list into a dict first to get around that:

```
counter = Counter(dict(myList))
```

If you're sure you're getting a list, you have some other bug we can't see.

Comment: Converting `myList` to a `dict` straight off may lose occurrences of values that need to be counted for multiple keys... `[('a', 5), ('a', 10)]` should probably be `('a', 15)` for instance... Whether that's an issue for the OP is another thing though...